# Recovering admin ID and password for local installation of MySQL

Tags: mysql, passwords, admin, password-recovery

I have MySQL installed locally on my Windows 7 Pro (64-bit) laptop.

I remember setting `admin` credentials but do not recall any details and was not able to locate my notes.

What can I do short of reinstalling the entire product?

I have found [some links](https://www.google.com/#q=MySQL%20admin%20password%20recovery) for restoring `ROOT` password but I'm not sure whether it's actually the same as `admin` password.

I'm not even sure what other information that I can provide could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

root is the MySQL system administrator.

Unless you've set up another user called admin, then you'll get what you want by resetting the root password.  Else if you have another user called admin, after you reset your root password you can go about setting your admin password.

Comment: Are any methods *safer* than other?